# Can't select or change selection with jquery to jq-idealform radiofield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, checked

I'm using [jq-idealforms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) to build a nice and easy form. In It i have a radio-field that i would like to fill with jquery after getted info from db. [Here](http://elclanrs.github.io/jq-idealforms/) there an example (at "step2".. section 2) you can watch how jq-ideal and radio-field work.
It doesn't provide an api to do that, but if i can fill an input[type='text'] element whit jquery, it must be possible whit radio-field too.

You can look [here](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms/blob/master/js/src/radiocheck.js#L24), how jq-idealforms manages radio-field.

I have tryed with the follow part of code:

```
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
  $(this).next().addClass('checked');
```

where $(this) is one of the 3 radio-field, and it is the one which i want select (rest of code [is on the example](http://elclanrs.github.io/jq-idealforms/)):

```
  <input type="radio" name="radio" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;" autocomplete="off">
```

The class "checked" is not putted in the element span.ideal-radio (sibling of input). I'm sure of the DOM, because if i use another class like "foo", this one is added. I think that is a bug from plugin, but what? how i can solve?

And at the and i reload form like explained on documentation:
      $(form).data('idealforms').reload().fresh();

Textarea elements and input text type are filled correctly.

Edit:

The problems is more simple, i can't select the first element of my radio checkbox if jq-idealforms is enabled, if i don't use jq-idealforms, the first radio element is selected. Or if you put "checked" on the second radio-element and you use jq-idealforms, it works too.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.idealforms.min.css" media="screen"/>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.idealforms.min.js"></script> <!-- removing it work -->
<head>
<body>
    <form id="form-doc" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <label>Tipo doc:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="tipo_doc" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Ruolo ditta:</label> 
        <label> 
            <input type="radio" name="ruolo_ditta" checked/>Fornitore
        </label> 
        <label> 
            <input type="radio" name="ruolo_ditta" /> Cliente
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Salva</button>
        <button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        onFail: function() {alert( 'fail');},
        onSuccess: function() {alert( 'succes');},
        inputs: {
            'tipo_doc' : {
                filters: 'required min max',
                data: { min: 3, max: 16 },
            }, 
            'ruolo_ditta' : {
                filters: 'required min',
                data: { min: 1 },
            }, 
        }
    };
    var myform = $('#form-doc').idealforms(options).data('idealforms');
    $('#reset').click(function(){
        myform.reset().fresh().focusFirst();
    });
    myform.focusFirst();
</script>`
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work with jquery-1.9.1 and jquery-1.10.1.

SOLUTION:

Documentation is wrong for radio button. You can read on [site](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms#required):

> required
>
> The field is required. This filter ONLY works with text inputs (text,
>   password, textarea). For select use exclude to exclude the default
>   option. **For radio and checkbox use min: 1 which will require at least
>   one option to be checked.**

But using:

```
'ruolo_ditta' : {
    filters: 'min',
    data: { min: 1 },
}
```

or combinated whit 'required' filters (or only required filter) on idealforms option, where "ruolo_ditta" is the value of attribute name of radio elements. The form make a wrong and realy strange behavior.

Deleting it, using checked on the first radio html element works good and

```
$(this).prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

works as aspected.

thanks,
j.

Comment: A new release of jq-idealforms (version 3) are released. It's not compatible with the previous version so i have not tryed it, but the author say that it would fix this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `reload` on the form if you are altering values [project doc](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms#reload)

Comment: Yes, i do it. Now i have added this information on my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin abstracts the visual indication of check from the actual property of check, so you have to do one of two things:

- trigger the check with a programmatic click:

`$(this).trigger('click');`

this is as if you were actually clicking on the checkbox. but this could also uncheck a previously checked box.  if that's not what you want, use option 2 which ensure that it's checked

- ensure that it's checked:

`$(this).prop('checked', true).trigger('change');`

Comment: whit $(this).trigger('click') is setted the class "ideal-field-focus" on <span class="ideal-field ideal-radiocheck"> (the constainer) and the radio button on which click is triggered is surrounded by a purple area adding "focus" class on <span class="ideal-radio"></span>, but not selected, whit the second trigger nothing at all.

Comment: $(this).prop('checked', true).trigger('change'); do the right thing only if i fire it for the second radio button. (There are 2 radio to chose and the form is created with nothing selected). For the first radio doesn't work properly. Sorry i have written the first comment trying it only in the first radio.

Comment: Now i'm trying to set the first radio by html. And i can't too. Looking on html input element i see that all slash at end are not present, but i insert it. <input ... /(<--this)>

Comment: `$(this).trigger('click')` should have the exact same effect as clicking on the button with your mouse.  try and verify that this is referring the the right object.  you may need to specify the radio button or attached label being clicked, and not some element added by jq-idealform.

Comment: Thanks another time for your attention. I have tryed, and i am sure that $(this) refer to input element that i need to select. Looking on [source](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms/blob/master/js/src/radiocheck.js#L24) of jq-idealforms you can see what's happen on click. `click: function() {$(this).trigger('focus') }`. `$(this).trigger('change')` works but only on the second radio buttons. And i still stuck on the same code. gh!